# How to Rout to a Component with Angular (2)

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to Rout to e Component:

My route:

```
const routes: Routes = [


 {
    path: 'apply', //name of the route
    component: Application //component to load when route is hit
  }
];
```

M App Module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule,ViewContainerRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule}   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { ApplyFormComponent } from './apply-form/apply-form.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MdInputModule,MdSelectModule,MdButtonModule} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    ApplyFormComponent],
  schemas: [NgModule],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdSelectModule,
    MdButtonModule
  ],
  exports: [MdInputModule,MdSelectModule,MdButtonModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [ApplyFormComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My component is called ApplyFormComponent. And it only puts out a litle Tex like : Hello world.

After i want to change the route (route link) to /apply i get an error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for Application. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for Application. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

I searched very long, but can't get any idea. Al should be right...

cheers

Comment: please check the docs before creating a question https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: @Jota.Toledo i've did it already....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to route to ApplyFormComponent on /apply path, you need to make changes as below.

```
    const routes: Routes = [

 {
    path: 'apply', //name of the route
    component: ApplyFormComponent //component to load when route is hit
  }
];
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please vote up and mark as answer if it helped.